# Deleting GDIPlus Bitmap cannot reduce memory usage

Tags: c++, gdi+

I have a code that new Bitmap, but when I use delete, the memory usage in Task Manager is not reduced.

My code is as below

```
Bitmap* pBuffer = new Bitmap(pMainImage->GetWidth(),  pMainImage->GetHeight());
delete pBuffer;
```

How to delete pBuffer above appropriately? So the memory usage return to the level before new Bitmap() is called.

Comment: What Task Manager shows doesn't decrease after you free memory. It's up for new allocations.

Answer (score 2):

That's just not how the Windows memory manager works.  When you release memory, the heap blocks just get marked as "not in use".  Available for the next allocation.  It *does* coalesce free blocks and decommits the virtual address space but it is not in a hurry to do so.  The exact rules it uses are not documented and vary by operating system version.

Task Manager is otherwise not up the job to be a reliable indicator of actual virtual memory in use.  Most of all because that is not simple to do.  The HeapWalk() api function can do it but comes with a strong warning that actually using it has detrimental side-effects.  Caused by it having to take too many locks to make it safe.  Only a debugger that freezes all threads could do it without those side-effects.  Like Windbg's !heap command.